# android usb adb driver for htc desire hd

Tags: android

Does anyone know what to edit in the android_winusb.inf file of the usb_driver folder inside the android sdk folder if I want to add the new HTC Desire HD device to it?

I've read people posting different things to add for different devices. I could not find what to add for HTC Desire HD.

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just Connect your phone in usb mode.. the HTC Sense setup will be present on the memory...

Answer (score 25):

The problem has been solved with the help of the following blog.
http://www.jmedved.com/2010/06/android-debug-bridge-on-htc-desire/

I have added following lines for the .inf file located in ..\Android\android-sdk-windows\google-usb_driver\android_winusb.inf :

```
;HTC Desire HD
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\Vid_0bb4&Pid_0ca2
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\Vid_0bb4&Pid_0ca2&MI_01
```

Since device and hardware ids are not listed in the inf file. For all the new devices if the driver is not found. We need to edit .inf file.

Answer (score 6):

Another way of getting adb to work with the device is to install HTC Sync (tested with version 3.0.5481). Apparently it will install the right USB drivers.

Answer (score 5):

I tried the blog post, mentioned above - but it failed on Windows 7 pro (on MacBook Pro using Bootcamp). However using HTC Sync like Sylvain mentioned above works perfectly on version 3.0.5511.

1. Download and install HTC Sync using [this guide](https://support.htc.com/alerts_downloads/en/HTC_Sync_and_Sync_Manager_for_all_HTC_Android_Phones).
2. Start HTC Sync
3. Connect your phone to PC with USB-cable

Now you see the installation of the USB-driver functioning and you are set up to test developing apps on your HTC Desire HD. You can also [take screenshots using the DDMS](http://myhtcdesire.com/tutorials/how-to-take-screenshots) located in the tools folder of your Android-sdk. The best part - you don't have too root your phone!

[image]

Comment: Current link for HTC sync:
https://support.htc.com/alerts_downloads/en/HTC_Sync_and_Sync_Manager_for_all_HTC_Android_Phones

Comment: Also note that you can unistall HTC Sync after the device driver works.

Comment: @Nux this post is 2,5 years old :-)

Comment: And today it is 3.5 years old. And I'm glad to have found it. Particularly the information provided by @Nux on the possibility to uninstall HTC Sync once the driver is installed. Current download location for [HTC Sync](http://www.htc.com/us/software/htc-sync/).

Answer (score 5):

The driver for x86 and x86-64 systems without any other tools like HTC Sync etc.:

http://www.android-hilfe.de/root-hacking-modding-fuer-htc-desire-hd/140744-erledigt-usb-adb-treiber.html#post1924269 *(Linked page is german, just klick on the Winzip-like icon)*